# Why i can't fill my screen with background with Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

Please help me, i don't have web dev experience, and i work in my friend project. I follow a tutorial from youtube about tailwind and react. In the video, he can fill his whole screen using this code:
[image]

So i try it in my Dashboard function:

```
import React from "react";

function Dashboard(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <section className=" bg-slate-700 min-h-screen">
          hello
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

but i get:
[image]

This is my project structure looks like:

[image]

Why can't i get the same result as the tutorial?

Comment: Try this className=" bg-slate-700 w-screen min-h-screen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are using inside a tag which has not to much content in it If you want to apply the color on the full screen you have to use the class "**w-screen and min-h-screen**" by which that tag gets the full width of the screen and full height